# view file containing DOS text (box-drawing characters, CRLF line terminators) and escape sequences

Tags: character-encoding, text, newlines

I have stumbled upon a strange text file in an archive of an old dos game downloaded from some abandonware site.

The text file is named `WHY_NOT.TXT`. I assume the file is some sort of [.NFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.nfo) file from the group of people who ... um ... 'liberated' the game.

I had not much luck viewing the file using cat or less or even [nfoview](http://home.gna.org/nfoview/).

The question is: how can I view the content of the file as intended?

Output from nfoview:

[image: nfoview]

Here is the output of cat and less. I use screenshots because I fear the encoding will get messed up more by the browser and the internets.

[image: catless]

Output of file:

```
$ file WHY_NOT.TXT 
WHY_NOT.TXT: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators, with escape sequences
```

Here is the file in raw hex dump created using `xxd -p WHY_NOT.TXT`:

```
1b5b34306d0d0a1b5b33396d1b5b34306d0d0a1b5b33396d1b5b34431b5b
303b33346ddb1b5b316ddbdfdfdfdfdfdf201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316d
dbdfdfdfdfdfdb201b5b34346d201b5b34306ddbdfdfdfdfdfdb201b5b30
3b33346ddb1b5b316ddbdfdfdbdfdfdb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb
1b5b36431b5b34346d201b5b34306ddbdfdfdfdfdfdb201b5b303b33346d
db1b5b316ddbdfdfdb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b303b3334
6ddb1b5b316ddbdfdfdfdfdfdc0d0a202020201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b31
6ddbdcdcdcdcdcdc201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddbdcdcdcdc1b5b3434
6ddc1b5b34306ddb201b5b34346d201b5b34306ddbdcdcdcdc1b5b34346d
dc1b5b34306ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb
1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b
316ddb1b5b36431b5b34346d201b5b34306ddbdcdcdcdc1b5b34346ddc1b
5b34306ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b
316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316d
db202020201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb0d0a1b5b3130431b5b303b33
346ddc1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb1b5b37431b5b3434
6d201b5b34306ddb202020201b5b303b33346ddc1b5b316ddb201b5b303b
33346ddb1b5b316ddb202020201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b30
3b33346ddb1b5b316ddb1b5b36431b5b34346d201b5b34306ddb20202020
1b5b303b33346ddc1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b
303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b303b
33346ddb1b5b316ddb202020201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb0d0a2020
20201b5b303b33346ddc1b5b316ddcdcdcdcdc1b5b34346ddc1b5b34306d
db201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb1b5b37431b5b34346d201b5b34306d
db202020201b5b34346d201b5b34306ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316d
db202020201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b31
6ddbdcdcdcdcdc201b5b34346d201b5b34306ddb202020201b5b34346d20
1b5b34306ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b
5b316ddbdc1b5b34346ddc1b5b34306ddb201b5b303b33346ddb1b5b316d
dbdcdcdcdc1b5b34346ddc1b5b34306ddf0d0a1b5b306d1b5b323535440d
0a
```

You can recreate the original file by copying that string to a file and then use `xxd -r -p filename`. Here is the md5sum to be really sure that you have the identical original file: `e64665b3f6e5fb3ec71c8fbf6cc63875`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's MSDOS charset.

Try `recode cp437..u8` in a UTF8 terminal.

It gives:

```
██▀▀▀▀▀▀ ██▀▀▀▀▀█  █▀▀▀▀▀█ ██▀▀█▀▀█ ██       █▀▀▀▀▀█ ██▀▀█ ██ ██▀▀▀▀▀▄
██▄▄▄▄▄▄ ██▄▄▄▄▄█  █▄▄▄▄▄█ ██ ██ ██ ██       █▄▄▄▄▄█ ██ ██ ██ ██    ██
      ▄█ ██        █    ▄█ ██    ██ ██       █    ▄█ ██ ██ ██ ██    ██
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█ ██        █     █ ██    ██ ██▄▄▄▄▄  █     █ ██ ██▄▄█ ██▄▄▄▄▄▀
```

in colour.

Comment: +1 for the CP437 hint. The `file` heuristic gets the character set completely wrong, somewhat unsurprisingly, given that it's not really text, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Some clues about the color:

The `ESC[0;33m;` things are [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) used for adding color to console output. 'ESC' in ascii is decimal 27 or octal 33, so you can pass that to the shell with `\\033` and see what I mean:

```
echo -e "\\033[0;32mgreen \\033[1mbright \\033[44mon blue\\033[0m and reset..."
```

Remember, the `\\033` is ESC.  Look familiar?  A lot of them only set the background, and some of the file is spaces -- hence the stylized SPAMLAND.

Note that those sequences don't work on the MS windows terminal emulator.

Comment: Some of the ANSI codes are actually [cursor movement](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint about **recode** Stéphane Chazelas.

I had another nfo file and it used CP866.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866

The code page was shown in the list of different encodings in the mousepad text editor.

So for viewing that file I just used this command:

```
cat fairlight.nfo |  recode cp866..u8 | less
```

Comment: How did you determine what code page your file used? … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.